# Can't get "generate summary report" to work in Clockify Api

Tags: api, clockify

I've been trying to generate a report with the Clockify api, and I've been following the [official documentation](https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#tag-Summary-report). First I tried with my own data, but after trial and error, I started even trying the default data. No luck either. According to the documentation, this should work:

```
   curl -X POST -H 'X-Api-Key: {apikey}' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
    "startDate": "2018-06-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-06-24T23:59:59.999Z",
    "me": "false",
    "userGroupIds": "[]",
    "userIds": "[]",
    "projectIds": "[]",
    "clientIds": "[]",
    "taskIds": "[]",
    "tagIds": "[]",
    "billable": "BOTH",
    "includeTimeEntries": "true",
    "zoomLevel": "week",
    "description": "",
    "archived": "Active",
    "roundingOn": "false"
    }' -v -i 
 'https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/{workspace}/reports/summary/'
```

But it doesn't. The response will be:

```
{
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4a679880; line: 5, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.clockify.adapter.http.summaryReport.GetSummaryReportRequest[\"userGroupIds\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4a679880; line: 5, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.clockify.adapter.http.summaryReport.GetSummaryReportRequest[\"userGroupIds\"])",
  "code": 3002
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with their default data - the arrays shouldn't be surrounded in "", so the correct data would be:

```
{
    "startDate": "2018-06-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-06-24T23:59:59.999Z",
    "me": "false",
    "userGroupIds": [],
    "userIds": [],
    "projectIds": [],
    "clientIds": [],
    "taskIds": [],
    "tagIds": [],
    "billable": "BOTH",
    "includeTimeEntries": "true",
    "zoomLevel": "week",
    "description": "",
    "archived": "Active",
    "roundingOn": "false"
}
```

This was working for me but now I'm getting a "No enum constant com.clockify.domain.model.DashboardSelection.false" error (code 3002) and I haven't been able to figure it out. The JSON I was using was working yesterday but today it is not... so not sure what is going on.

Edit: Remove the "me" field, it prevents the error that I'm getting. Instead just put in your user ID into the userIds field if you only want your own entries.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
data = {
    "startDate":f"{start}T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": f"{end}T23:59:59.999Z",
    "me": "false",
    "userGroupIds": [],
    "userIds": [],
    "projectIds": [],
    "clientIds": [],
    "taskIds": [],
    "tagIds": [],
    "billable": "BOTH",
    "includeTimeEntries": True,
    "zoomLevel": "month",
    "description": "",
    "archived": "Active",
    "roundingOn": False 
}
```